# no permanent file created

Tags: file, logstash, virtualbox

I'm running a conf file in logstash which gives the output as required but when i open ls to list file it's not getting created.need help in resolving issue.

**conf file:**

```
input {
  elasticsearch{
    hosts =>"localhost:9200"
    index=>"index1"
  }
}
output{
  file{
    path => "/opt/elk/logstash-6.5.0/example.json"
  }
  stdout{}
}
```

**Result of execution:**

```
[2019-10-13T14:07:47,503][INFO ][logstash.outputs.file    ] 
Opening file {:path=>"/opt/elk/logstash-6.5.0/example.json"}
{
"@timestamp" => 2019-10-13T08:37:46.715Z,
   "example" => [
        //data within example//
  }

[2019-10-13T16:44:19,982][INFO ][logstash.pipeline] Pipeline has        terminated {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x4f8848b run>"}
```

but when I run ls to see example.json, it doesn't show up
ls command:

```
elastic@es-VirtualBox:~/opt/elk/logstash-6.5.0$ ls
bin  CONTRIBUTORS  fetch.conf  Gemfile.lock  lib   logs             logstash-core-plugin-api  NOTICE.TXT   throw.conf  vendor config  data          Gemfile     grokexample.conf  LICENSE.txt  logstash-core  modules                   output.json  tools       x-pack
```

so was wondering if conf only creates a temporary file?

Comment: What happens when you remove the stdout-output and only have the file-output active?

Comment: Are you looking into the correct directory? `/opt/elk/logstash-6.5.0/` is not the same as `~/opt/elk/logstash-6.5.0/`, the second one is inside your home directory, but your config is writing to `/opt/elk/logstash-6.5.0/`

Comment: Yea sorry for late reply I forgot I was running it as root so it was writing it in at root folder i found the file there thx for the advice @leandro